# Retraction on Connected Space

Tags: general-topology

Does there exist a retraction from a connected topological space to a subspacce with exactly two points.

Will somebody please give me a hint for this one or at least a good way to start. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know any theorems about continuous functions $f:X \to Y$ such that $X$ is connected?

Comment: Well I cannot necessarily say that Y is connected since I don't know that f is a homeomorphism. Right now I can't think of anything that could be useful.

Comment: @Musicpulpite Can you think of anything related to the image of $f$?

Comment: As it turns out f(X)<Y is connected. Now if {X1,x2} is disconnected then there doesn't exist a retraction(since f is necessarily non constant). Is that the case?

Comment: That looks correct.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer, @Musicpulpite.

Comment: Ok. Thank you both. I'll flesh this guy out and have it up tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Alright everybody,
with the help of Mike Miller and Lee Mosher we can show that this somewhat intuitive notion about retractions is correct.

The quickest way is by contradiction:
Assume that there is a retraction $f:X\rightarrow[x_{1},x_{2}]$ (i.e. continuous function such that $f(x_{1})=x_{1} \mbox{and} f(x_{2})=x_{2}$).

Now since $[x_{1},x_{2}]$ is disconnected  and f is continuous $f^-1(x_{1})$ and $f^-1(x_{2})$ are disjoint,nonempty open sets in X. This is a stark contradiction of the fact that X is connected. Therefore there does not exist a retraction from a connected set to a subset with exactly two points.

Comment: There can be disjoint non empty open sets in $X$. I think you need one more descriptor of $f^{-1}(x_1)$ and $f^{-1}(x_2)$

Comment: You are right. These two sets are complements of each other since the inverse image comes from the original space X. I.e. $f^-1(x_{1})\cup f^-1(x_{2})=X$

Comment: May I suggest using the edit button to update your answer? also instead of f^-1 try f^{-1}. Note the difference between  $f^-1$ and $f^{-1}$.